# How to retain values of parent component in child on every click in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing, parent-child

I have written a code in which I am creating a treeview structure in angular 2.

Parent Component HTML:

```
   <child-component [data]="tree"></child-component>
```

Parent Component.ts file has the following:

```
  tree: TreeData[] = [];
    treeData: TreeData;

    ngOnInit() {
    this.tree.push({answer:'first',child:[]});
    this.treeData = this.tree[0];
  }
```

I have created a class in the common.ts file which has answer(input in the textbox) and child(it will get populated recursively when add node is clicked) :

```
export class TreeData {
  answer: string;
  child: TreeData[];
  constructor(answer: string, child: TreeData[]) {
    this.answer = answer;
    this.child = child;
  }
}
```

Child component's html:

```
<li *ngFor="#eachChild of data ; let i = index">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputData" required/>
    <child-component [data]="eachChild.child"></child-component>
</li>
```

Child component's ts file:

```
 @Input() data : TreeData[];
  inputData: any = null;
 eachChild: TreeData;
  add(inputData: any, index: number) {
    this.data[index].child.push({answer: inputData, child: []});  
  }
```

[Current output treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSrKX.png)
:The output looks like this when clicked on add Node, a new text box gets added below

The actual output should be like a tree structure (when add node is clicked, new textbox gets added as its child)

The issue is that the object gets refreshed on every click and is not able to retain the previous state. The contents should get appended but this seems like a new instance is created every time. Any insight on how I can proceed with this to create a treeView in angular 2?

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle or codepen? Would make it easier to help you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uXbn6/4484/  This is the jsfiddle in which I have used Angular 1. I want to achieve the sane functionality in angular 2. But since ng-include etc are not there in angular 2, I have resorted to the above mentioned approach.

Comment: Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?